# How To Refresh Ng-repeat With AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I am creating a table with few data. I don't want to load all the data at once. So I create a button on view when the user click that buttoon then it hit the server and take the next 4 datasets. At one time only 4 data will.

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="paginateEmail" >
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Fail Agent</h3>
            </div>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                <th>
                    Email
                </th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in email1.emailList3">
                        <td>
                           {{item}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <td>
                <form ng-controller="paginateEmail" ng-submit="submitForm()">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Previous</button>&nbsp;<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Next</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

and controller code is -

```
basicInfo.controller("paginateEmail", function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.email1 = {
            emailList3: []
        };
    var current=1    
    $scope.submitForm = function () {           
        $scope.email1.emailList3.length=0;
        $http({method: 'GET', url: "../Dashboard/failAgentsList?current="+current}).
            success(function (data) {
                var i = 0;                   
                for(i=0;i<data.list.length;i++){                        
                    $scope.email1.emailList3.push(data.list[i]);
                }                    
                current+=1
            });
        console.log(current)
    }
        $scope.submitForm();
    }
);
```

after that the data is successfully binded with the scope.email1.emailList3 but the view is not refreshed. I want that after clicking the next button the view is also refreshed with new data which were bind by the loop in controller.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you move `emailList3` to be directly on the `$scope`, i.e., `$scope.emailList3 = []`?  Angular is not deep watching your objects, so it doesn't see the change; however, if the array was directly on the scope, it would update the view.  Otherwise, you could call `$scope.$apply()` after the `for` loop, but I'd try to avoid that

Comment: `$http` returns a promise, which can be handled by calling the method `then`. Promises should already be integrated in the angular lifecycle; I'm pretty sure that if you update `$scope.email1...` in the success handler of the promise the view should update without the manual call to `$apply`.

Comment: I put together a small [pen](http://codepen.io/simonedavico/pen/bNZQwm) demonstrating it. `$timeout` returns a promise, exactly like `$http`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem you can add setTimeout but it is not the correct way to do this because, some times the server take more time to fetch data.

```
setTimeout(function () {        
    $scope.email1.length = 0;
    $http({method: 'GET', url: '../Dashboard/confirmAgentList'}).
        success(function (data) {
            var i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < data.confAgentList.length; i++) {
                $scope.email1.push(data.confAgentList[i]);                    
                }
               //and write you additional logic here
            }
        })
}, 500);
```

Comment: Its advised to use $timeout instead of setTimeout, which handles $scope.$apply correctly

Answer (score 0):

You need to start a digest cycle to have it update the view. Inside your success method use the $apply method:

```
        success(function (data) {
            var i = 0;                   
            for(i=0;i<data.list.length;i++){                        
                $scope.email1.emailList3.push(data.list[i]);
            }          
            $rootScope.$apply();
            current+=1
        });
```

Comment: But I am getting this error when I apply $rootScope.$apply();
ReferenceError: $rootScope is not defined

Comment: maybe just `$scope.$apply`?

Comment: This is actually wrong, since $http.success is already executed inside a $scope.$apply, so you should never need to do this, or you will start seeing [$rootScope:inprog] errors.